# How to modify Contacts/Lead related to a Task with a TaskRelation upon Task Creation

Tags: apex, trigger, taskrelation

We have some APEX code that relates Contacts and possibly a Lead to a Task using one or more TaskRelation objects. Therefore the pseudocode is:

```java
Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(newTasks, false);
TaskRelation rel = new TaskRelation();
rel.TaskId = srList[0].Id;
rel.RelationId = whoId;
insert rel;
```

The problem is that now we have some users who want to write a trigger to update the Contacts/Lead related to the Task when this is created, however:

- before and after insert trigger on Task does not have a `WhoId` nor `TaskRelation` objects that still have to be inserted in the Database
- Salesforce does not allow to create a trigger on TaskRelation

It might be possible to solve this using a scheduled Process built with ProcessBuilder as explained [here](https://douglascayers.com/2016/12/26/how-to-update-leads-or-contacts-when-shared-activities-logged/) but is it really impossible to do that with APEX?

Note that after the `TaskRelation` objects are inserted Salesforce will update the `Task.WhoId` to match one of these `TaskRelation.RelationId` but no trigger is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, at least as long as we're talking about UI updates, you should just be able to use a future method or Queueable method; you can acquire a record lock on the activity as soon as the transaction completes, where the TaskRelation records should then be available.

Comment: Unfortunately we are talking about APEX updates but that's an interesting suggestion, how do you think a future method will help? Are you suggesting to call the future method from the trigger on the Task object? 

Alternatively, is there a way to be notified when the execution of an APEX endpoint, like a REST class or a VisualForce page, terminates?

Comment: @Perennialista The future/queueable method could be called from a trigger. It will not execute until the transaction completes (e.g. the VF page or API call has completed).

Comment: you are right I have tested with a future method and that works! That is amazing! Thank you!